Многопоточность в проверке ссылок c#
Допустим есть список ссылок в файле, которые нужно проверить.
С одним потоком, всё придельно понятно и допустимо, если ссылок в районе 20-50.
Но, когда ссылок 500-600, процесс проверки занимает очень много времени.
Вопрос состоит в том, что лучше использовать, в плане многопоточности чтобы проверить ссылки в файле быстрее ?
Вот пример кода по которому работает сам процесс обработки.
    public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;  //Tell the user how the process went
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; //Allow for the process to be cancelled
}

//Start Process
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

//Cancel Process
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Check if background worker is doing anything and send a cancellation if it is
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }

}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);

        //Check if there is a request to cancel the process
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
            return;
        }
    }
    //If the process exits the loop, ensure that progress is set to 100%
    //Remember in the loop we set i < 100 so in theory the process will complete at 99%
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
         lblStatus.Text = "Process was cancelled";
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
         lblStatus.Text = "There was an error running the process. The thread aborted";
    }
    else
    {
       lblStatus.Text = "Process was completed";
    }
    }


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
